# is it possible to use output of inner query to input of outer query where caluse?

Tags: mysql, hive, hivecli

like

```
select ho from (select sourceaddress,count(sourceaddress) as 
src,hour(eventtime) as ho 
from default.fullandfinal 
where sourceaddress='0.0.0.0' and  eventtime between '2019-05-11 00:00:00' and 
'2019-05-11 19:59:59'  
group by sourceaddress,hour(eventtime) order by sourceaddress,ho) t where 
src=28350;
```

the output of this query is **11** and i want to use this output in my nxt     query which is

```
select sourceaddress,destinationaddress,destinationport,name,count(*) as count  
from fullandfinal 
where eventtime like "11%" and sourceaddress='0.0.0.0'  
group by sourceaddress,destinationaddress,destinationport,name 
order by count desc limit 5;
```

i want to write single query for this is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering MySQL - Yes possible. You have to use the first query as Sub Query in the second Query. The query structure will be something like this-

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ....) AS [From Other Query] -- In the selection part 
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE TABLE_2.ID = (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ....) -- In Where condition
```

For both above case, you have to make sure your sub query returns one single value that is like 11 you mentioned.

Try This-

```
SELECT sourceaddress,
destinationaddress,
destinationport,
[name],
COUNT(*) as [count]  
FROM fullandfinal 
WHERE 
eventtime LIKE
(
    SELECT ho FROM 
    (
        SELECT sourceaddress,
        COUNT(sourceaddress) AS src,
        HOUR(eventtime) AS ho 
        FROM DEFAULT.fullandfinal 
        WHERE sourceaddress='0.0.0.0' 
        AND  eventtime BETWEEN '2019-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-11 19:59:59'  
        GROUP BY sourceaddress,
        HOUR(eventtime) 
        ORDER BY sourceaddress,ho
    ) t
    WHERE src=28350
) + '%' 
AND sourceaddress='0.0.0.0'  
GROUP BY sourceaddress,destinationaddress,destinationport,name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
limit 5;
```

Comment: There is only one table @mkRabbani

Comment: No issue, both case use table reference TABLE_1. I just shown the structure  for your reference.

Comment: i m not getting what you are tying to say please explain in  brief . Or  arrange the above query as per our requirement.  @mkRabbani

Comment: Where you wants to use 11 (Output from query 1)  in Query 2?

Comment: One clarification, I am talking about MySQL database that seems initially tagged in your post.

Comment: I updated the query please check this. I want like that..@mkRabbani

Comment: @vishwajeet Check the added script work for you or not.

Comment: SELECT sourceaddress,destinationaddress,destinationport,name,COUNT(*) as count1  FROM fullandfinal WHERE eventtime LIKE "2019-05-11 (SELECT ho FROM (SELECT sourceaddress,COUNT(sourceaddress) AS src,HOUR(eventtime) AS ho FROM fullandfinal WHERE sourceaddress='192.168.6.2' and  eventtime BETWEEN '2019-05-11 00:00:00' and '2019-05-11 19:59:59' group by sourceaddress,HOUR(eventtime) ORDER BY sourceaddress,ho) t WHERE src=28350)%" and sourceaddress='192.168.6.2' group by sourceaddress,destinationaddress,destinationport,name limit 5..it is showing none output @mkRabbani